# Script crashes when called from a second script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qpixmap

I have a report generation script (let's call this script A)that generates a PDF report. I want to import this in a new script (script B) and call the functions from within this new script.

The problem:

> 1. Script A crashes when called from Script B exactly at the creation of a QPixmap object. Python console restarts.
> 2. Script A runs fine when it is run on its own, but if I try to call it from Command Prompt python.exe crashes.

The following is Script B. All it does is it imports Script A, creates an instance of a class defined in A, and uses that to call a method of that object.

```
import Script A as et

a = "sample"
mdbPath = "C:\\Python27\\test.mdb"
directory = "C:\\Python27"

ui = et.HawkAutomationScript()
ui.Main(mdbPath,directory,a)
```

Script A contains the definition of a class called HawkAutomationScript. This object contains two functions to note: one Main function and one function to generate the report. These are the imported modules:

```
from random import*
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTextDocument, QPrinter, QApplication, QPainter
from string import Template
import shutil
import time
import pyodbc
```

This is the definition of the class and the Main function:

```
doc = QTextDocument()
myCursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)

class HawkAutomationScript(object):
    def Main(self,mdb,directory,name):
            Ui_FormObject = HawkAutomationScript()
##          Filling in the Report         ##
            Ui_FormObject.fnGenerateReport(directory,name)

def fnGenerateReport(self,directory,name):
        now = datetime.now()
        dateString = now.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")                           # For getting Current Date
        dirPath = "C:\\"

        ResultName = "SelfTest_Results"
        testName = name+".pdf"
        subDirPath = dirPath + name 
        if(os.path.isdir(dirPath)):
                if(os.path.isdir(subDirPath)):
                        subDirPath = subDirPath + testName
                else:
                        os.mkdir(subDirPath)
                        subDirPath = subDirPath + testName
        else:
                os.mkdir(dirPath)
                os.mkdir(subDirPath)
                subDirPath = subDirPath + testName
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(doc.size().width(), doc.size().height()) ################
        printer = QPrinter()

        printer.setOutputFileName(subDirPath)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

        doc.print_(printer)
        # Create a QPainter to draw our content    
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.begin( printer )
        doc.drawContents(painter)
        painter.end()
```

This is all the relevant code and it is runnable.

If I run script B, A crashes at the QPixmap line marked in the code. But if I copy the lines from B and run A on its own, the PDF report is generated. But if I run A on its own from Command Prompt python.exe crashes.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: What is the error message when the script crashes?

Comment: There isn't any error message in the output. When I run it in the console, the shell restarts after the QPixmap line. If the run from command prompt I just get a pop up saying "python.exe" has crashed.